# Cardboard cut out, cutout or cut-out?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, hyphens

I couldn't find an agreement online on which form of "cut out" is the most correct as a noun.

It would be interesting to know about any British English and U.S. English distinction as well.

Comment: The online dictionaries I can see prefer _cut-out_ (to disambiguate from the verb _cut out_). Oxford gives _cutout_ as an alternative, though my spellchecker doesn't like it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are referring to a single entity, "cut out" is a poor choice. "Cutout" is correct. According to Google, there is no word "cut-out". **But** it is my personal policy that when I am unsure if a compound word is valid then I am bold and unafraid to use a hyphenated form, for when doing so there is little doubt that the reader will know precisely what I mean.

Comment: Thanks this actually clears it up for me. Easy and wonderful explanation.

Comment: If this answers your question, you should accept it by clicking the "green tick".

Comment: Done. Ngram proves the "cardboard cutout" form to be most widely used too. [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cardboard+cut+out%2Ccardboard+cut-out%2Ccardboard+cutout&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccardboard%20cut%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccardboard%20cut%20-%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccardboard%20cutout%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you can't find any consensus is that no consensus exists.

Feel free to choose.  [Ngrams suggests](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cardboard%20cut-out%2Ccardboard%20cut%20out%2Ccardboard%20cutout&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccardboard%20cut%20-%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccardboard%20cut%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccardboard%20cutout%3B%2Cc0) that "cutout"  is several times more common than cut out or cut-out.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have attempted a similar comparison with the Open iWeb Corpus Dictionary and the results diverge with Ngram:
- Cut-out: 12379 entries
- Cutout 17923 entries
- Cut out: 131402 entries

With "Cut Out" being the most used.

https://www.english-corpora.org/iweb/

Comment: Did you use "cardboard cut out" as the search?  There are several other meanings of "cut out" that would pollute your results:  The engine cut out when I ran out of fuel" for example or "Cut out the pattern with scissors" @AlexF.

Comment: Good point. "cardboard cutout" it's the most widely use according to iWeb too. Thanks for the tip, and thanks for letting me discover Ngram. Extremely useful tool!